# ¿Como puedo imprimir numeros resultantes?

Tags: c

Realiza un programa que genere de manera aleatoria 80 números en el intervalo del conjunto del 1 al 100, que no se repitan, y después genera una lista con los 20 números que hagan falta, ejemplo con un conjunto de 10
números generando 8 al azar: {1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10} la lista con los que faltan son 3 y 8.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>


int main(){
int aleatorio, i, restantes;
srand(time(0));

for (i=0; i<80; i++){
  aleatorio = 1+ rand() %(101-1);  
printf("\n %d", aleatorio);
  
}


return 0;
```

}

Ya tengo los números aleatorios pero no se como imprimir los otros 20 aleatorios restantes, ¿alguien me podría ayudar por favor (lenguaje C)?

Comment: 1) Creas un array de int de largo 100. 2) haces un for para setear cada valor del array en cero. 3) En el for que ya tienes en tu código haces algo como miArray[i]=1. Con esto tendrías un array con 80 items en 1 y 20 en cero. 4) Finalmente haces otro for, con in if( miArray[i] == 0) y ahí encuentras tu valores

Comment: @Yussef no crees que sea más conveniente un array de `bool`?

Comment: @Mateo claro que si, mucho más conveniente.

Comment: Ya no entinedo, ayuda, voy bien, mal o que tango que hacer?

Comment: @Yussef Logre hacer una lista de 100 de largo donde todos son 0.  Tambien tenog el array de los 80 items en 1. Pero no se combinarlos y hacer el resto.

Comment: @Yussef      #include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int miArray[100], i;
    
    for ( i=0; i<100; i++) {
        miArray[i]=0;
    }
    printf("\n Los valores aleatorios son:");
    for ( i=0; i<100; i++) {
    printf("%d", miArray[i]);
    }
    
    int j, aleatorio ;
 srand(time(0));

    for (j=0; j<80; j++){
  aleatorio = 1;  
    printf("\n %d", aleatorio);
  
}


    return 0;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma sencilla es usar un arreglo auxiliar como un `cache` para saber que números aleatorios ya aparecieron y cuales no.

Tus números van del `1..100`, sin embargo, un arreglo tiene su primer indice en 0. Por lo que debes hacer dos cosas:

1. Crear un arreglo de 100 elementos.
2. Llena el arreglo de `0`s y úsalos como un valor booleano. 0 si el número no ha salido, y 1 cuando el número ya haya salido.
3. Los arreglos tienen su primer índice en 0, por lo que para saber si un numero ha aparecido, debes restar `-1` al número aleatorio. Por ejemplo, si te sale el número 1, su "posición" en el arreglo es el número 0.

El array debe ser de enteros, ya que como tal, el tipo de dato boolean no existe en `C` a menos que utilices `stdbool.h` en `C99`.

Después de sacar 80 números aleatorios diferentes, puedes recorrer el arreglo auxiliar e imprimir el indice de aquellas posiciones en las que su valor sea igual a 0, ya que indicaría que nunca aparecieron dichos números.

Te dejo el código con comentarios para que sea más sencillo entender la solución.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void print_array(int arr[], int size, int print_found_numbers)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == print_found_numbers)
            printf("%d : ", i + 1);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
}

int main() 
{
    // Inicializar array en 0
    // Numbers guardara 0 o 1. 1 indicando si el número ya apareció en los números random o no.
    int numbers[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        numbers[i] = 0;

    int aleatorio, contador;
    srand(time(0));

    contador = 0;
    while(contador < 80) {
        aleatorio = 1 + rand() % (101-1); 
        // Buscamos si el número ya apareció.
        // Debido a que la primer posición del se accede con 0, restamos un -1 al número aleatorio para tener su posición en el arreglo.
        if (numbers[aleatorio - 1] == 0) {
            // Número no ha aparecido, indicamos que ya se encontro e incrementamos el contador.
            numbers[aleatorio - 1] = 1;
            ++contador;
        }
    }

    // Imprimimos los números faltantes. Si el último parámetro se cambia a 1, imprimeremos los números que encontramos en el ciclo while.
    print_array(numbers, 100, 0);

    return 0;
}
```